# Visual Studio 2022 ASP.NET Core with Angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

If you follow the instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio and create a new VS project with "dotnet new angular -o my-new-app", when you open and run the project it fails to run.  The error is listed bellow.

Does anyone have a solution for how to get the standard Visual Studio 2022 "ASP.NET Core with Angular" project to work?

```
npm start

> newapp@0.0.0 prestart
> node aspnetcore-https


> newapp@0.0.0 start
> run-script-os


> newapp@0.0.0 start:windows
> ng serve --port 44486 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\ASP.NET\https\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\ASP.NET\https\%npm_package_name%.key

Node.js version v17.3.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
[HPM] Proxy created: [ '/weatherforecast' ]  ->  http://localhost:49901
node:internal/crypto/hash:67
this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (C:\Dev\BookWebSite\Source\Test\newApp\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:145:18)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (C:\Dev\BookWebSite\Source\Test\newApp\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:46:50)
    at RawSource.updateHash (C:\Dev\BookWebSite\Source\Test\newApp\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\RawSource.js:70:8)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Dev\BookWebSite\Source\Test\newApp\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:880:17)
    at handleParseResult (C:\Dev\BookWebSite\Source\Test\newApp\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:946:10)
    at C:\Dev\BookWebSite\Source\Test\newApp\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:1040:4
    at processResult (C:\Dev\BookWebSite\Source\Test\newApp\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:755:11)
    at C:\Dev\BookWebSite\Source\Test\newApp\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:819:5 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.3.0
```

Original Question:
It is possible that this project type is just not ready yet and should not be used by someone new to Angular.

I want to learn how to use Angular with .NET Core and Web API and it seems this project type should be a good fit.  I have not used npm much before, so most of this is new to me.  Last web stuff I did was using ASP.net MVC.

When I create the project in Visual Studio 2022 (17.0.4), I see several errors in the error list (not in the output window) because it cannot find various files in ClientApp/note_modules.

I ran npm update, then various other commands to update angular and so on, now I get all kinds of compile errors in what appears to be the Angular Typescript files.

If I try and run it from VS, it starts a page, then tries to build and gives the error below.  This leads me to believe this is probably only for expert users who are fully used to which versions of TypeScript, Angular, Node.js etc. they need for all this to work.

```
Error: src/api-authorization/authorize.service.ts:91:13 - error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.

91         if (popupError.message === 'Popup window closed') {
            ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/api-authorization/authorize.service.ts:104:29 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

104           return this.error(redirectError);
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/api-authorization/authorize.service.ts:139:27 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

139         return this.error(redirectSignOutError);
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/api-authorization/authorize.service.ts:152:25 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

152       return this.error(error);
```

Comment: Have you installed nodejs on your system? Either through the vs installer or nodejs.org? What do `node -v` and `npm -v` say?

Comment: npm -v returned 8.3.0  I did install node.js via VS, then also true to ensure that it was updated etc.  It just seems like if you need to run all kinds of steps to get the basic starting project to work that they should have a readme or something with that information.

Comment: Kan je eens de `tsconfig.json` en `tsconfig.app.json` ook posten in de vraag?

Comment: Ah en `npm update` heeft waarschijnlijk de package.json en tsconfig aangepast. What happens if you create a new project, run `npm install` instead, and run the project? Also, Visual Studio should run `npm install` for you when you run the project so actually there's no need to do it yourself...

Comment: Thanks, I will try the npm install after creating a new project.  The one issue I saw was that it said the Angular version needed to be at least version x.y (don't remember the numbers) to work with the .net core project.  It's weird to me that this does not work automatically, this is Windows after all.  :D

Comment: I think I am going to look for some regular tutorials.  I guess this is a bit like Linux, until you are an expert, nothing comes easy.  :D  I created a new project, ran it and got an error right away.  Then I checked npm -v and it showed 8.3.0.  I ran npm install, that showed several warnings and the version after that was still 8.3.0.  I then ran npm start and it gave some errors.  ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Comment: Meh.  My guess is that they will update that project template at some point so it works, but for now it's broken out of the box.

Comment: My guess was that `strict` mode is enabled in the tsconfig file, and this explains why you're getting this error, but it's hard to tell. You say the project comes from a vs template, but it doesn't look familiar to me. Could you perhaps push your code to github? Just create a new repo on github and follow the instructions on the page of your empty repo...

Comment: In VS 2022 just create a new project with the type "ASP.NET Core with Angular".  It has these issues out of the box.  I got it to work once by accident, but I don't know what I did.  I think it's going to be a case where you need a specific version of each of the components to work.

Comment: I also tried "dotnet new angular -o my-new-app" with the same result.  If I open the app in VS and run it, it tries to build it, but gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Seek out those rows and on the exception variable declaration add ":any"

Like this:

```
} catch (popupError: any) {
```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated VS 2022 to version 17.1.0.  I created a new Angular project like I did before, clicked F5 to run debug and hey presto, it initialized and showed me the hello world web page as expected.

I guess it was just a bug that they fixed.  Thanks MS.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in command line (windows). It cleared up the envelope error:

set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider